# How to stop for loop at present month and year value in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, calendar, break

Currently I have code as follows:

```
   mon = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m")
   month = int(mon)
   yy = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
   year = int(yy)
   print year

   for state_fips in (4,5,6):
       for year in range(1993, year+1):
           for j in range(1,13):
               yearMonth1 = year,j,state_fips
               yearMonth = year,j
               print yearMonth1
           if (yearMonth) == (year,month):
               break
```

It prints the response as :

```
(1993, 1, 4)
(1993, 2, 4)
(1993, 3, 4)... 
.
.
(1993, 1, 5)
(1993, 2, 5)
(1993, 3, 5)
.
.
(2017, 12, 6)
```

How to make this for loop end at 2017 / 03 i.e the current month and year instead of going till the end of year 2017?

Comment: Why the `strftime` then `int` dance? Why not just use `datetime.date.today().month` and `datetime.date.today().year` directly?

Comment: Your `if` statement is not indented far enough to matter for the `for j in range(1, 13)` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are overcomplicating extracting today's year and month. Just use the `year` and `month` attributes of the `date` object returned by `datetime.date.today()`:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
# in the loop we'll use (today.year, today.month)
```

In your loop you made two mistakes: you reused `year` (masking the current year value), and you put the `if` statement in the year loop, not the month loop, so the latter continues to 12, always.

You'll have to test the `month` variable in the *innermost* loop, not in the outer year loop, against the correct current year value. The outer loop ends naturally at the current year:

```
today = datetime.date.today()

for state_fips in (4,5,6):
    for year in xrange(1993, today.year + 1):
        for month in xrange(1,13):
            yearMonth1 = year, month, state_fips
            print yearMonth1
            # break out of month loop if this month is reached
            if (year, month) == (today.year, today.month):
                break
```

As you are using Python 2, I replaced the `range()`calls with `xrange()` to avoid creating lists just for iteration.

You could use the [`itertools.product` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to produce a single loop:

```
from itertools import product:

today = datetime.date.today()

years, months = xrange(1993, today.year + 1), xrange(1, 13)
for state_fips, year, month in product((4, 5, 6), years, months):
    yearMonth1 = year, month, state_fips
    print yearMonth1
    # break out of month loop if this month is reached
    if (year, month) == (today.year, today.month):
        break
```

Comment: yearMonth Value is the last one when used outside this loop. How to get it store all values?

Comment: @Viv: `yearMonth` is just `(year, month)`. I omitted it here because it didn't seem all that relevant when you already have `yearMonth1`.

Comment: Oops, I meant yearMonth1 how to get it to store the entire list of values that it is printing?

Comment: @Viv: use a list and append. But then you can just use `all_years_months =
 [(y, m, f) for f, y, m in product((4, 5, 6), years, months) if (y, m) < (today.year, today.month)]` and forgo the `for` loops altogether.